# Combining a descriptor class with dataclass and field

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I am using a dataclass and field to pass in a default value.
When an argument is provided I want to validate it using a descriptor class.

Is there any way to utilize the benefits of field (repr, default, init, etc) while getting the validator benefits of a descriptor class?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


class Descriptor:
    def __init__(self, default):
        self.default = default

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj:
            return vars(obj).get(self.name)
        else:
            return None

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if not value:
            value = self.default
        else:
            value = field(default=int(value), repr=False)
        vars(obj)[self.name] = value


@dataclass
class Person:
    age: str = Descriptor(field(default=3, repr=False))

    # Many additional attributes 
    # using same descriptor class


p = Person()
r = Person(2.37)
```

Comment: Why are you passing a `field` object to your descriptor object? Honestly, I think what you are trying to do is incompatible with `dataclass`.

Comment: Fields define actual instance attributes; descriptors (and properties in general, which I think you are trying to reimplement) are *class* attributes that have special behavior when accessed or assigned to.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to validate the input and also use the functionality of the field object.
In this case I would like to make the type as int.

Comment: Descriptor effectively supercede fields; I think you want something like `age = ClassVar(Descriptor(3))`, and `Descriptor` itself will handle storing the actual value in an attribute attached to its `obj` argument.

Comment: You may consider just using the `pydantic` library, which has a [`dataclass`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/dataclasses/) implementation that has validation. Otherwise, the standard library `dataclass` is not designed to allow what you are trying to do.

Comment: BTW, `vars(obj)[self.name] = value` *doesn't make any sense* where `value = field(default=int(value), repr=False)`...  Assigning a field to an instance attribute does nothing for you. The whole point of `dataclass` is that it introspects annotations in the class body to generate various boilerplalte methods *when the class itself is instantiated*.... it's *too late* by the time you are creating instances to do anything with that `field` object

Comment: Basically, people need to understand taht dataclasses are for a specific use-case, that is namely, *data classes*, classes that basically act as record types. They provide a way to avoid boilerplate, but you have to stick within the documented ways of creating a class definition. If you want to do anything else more fancy, then the *easiest solution is just not to use `dataclasses.dataclass`*

Comment: @chepner yes, but then you cannot really combine that with the field specification, at least not in any way that is obvious to me

Comment: I'm saying, don't use a `field` *at all*. `Descriptor.__set__` is fully responsible for any validation needed and setting a private backing attribute.

Comment: @chepner but then how will you get the dataclass to generate the `__init__`, `__repr__` etc using those attributes?

Comment: Use a separate `InitVar` and do the assignment in `__post_init__`, which admittedly is ugly because it would need a separate name like `age_`. (And that only handles initializing the attribute; it won't incorporate it into `__repr__` et all, because like you said, that's not what dataclasses are for.)

Comment: So yeah; mixing the two won't work, but neither will using a `Descriptor` alone...

Comment: Thanks guys reading this was super helpful

Answer (score 5):

You *can* use a descriptor with a `dataclasses.field` (at least after [this bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue33141) was fixed).

There are just a few things that needed to be changed in your code:

Starting in the `dataclass`, you had the order wrong as to which object is calling which object. The field object is what should be attached to the `dataclass` with the default of the `Descriptor`:

```py
@dataclass
class Person:
    age: str = field(default=Descriptor(default=3), repr=False)
```

Next in `Descriptor.__set__`, when the `age` argument is not provided to the constructor, the `value` argument will actually be the instance of the `Descriptor` class. So we need to change the guard to see if `value` is `self`:

```py
class Descriptor:
    ...
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if value is self:
            value = self.default
        ....
```

Finally, I made one more change to echo the patterns I've seen in the python ecosystem: using the `getattr` and `setattr` functions for getting and setting attributes on classes.

Unfortunately, this introduced an infinite recursion bug, so I changed the place the value is stored on the `Person` object to `_age`.

All that being said, this works as you intended:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


class Descriptor:
    def __init__(self, default):
        self.default = default

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.private_name = '_' + name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return getattr(obj, self.private_name)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if value is self:
            value = self.default
        else:
            value = int(value)
        setattr(obj, self.private_name, value)


@dataclass
class Person:
    age: str = field(default=Descriptor(default=3), repr=False)

    # Many additional attributes
    # using same descriptor class


r = Person(2.37)
assert r.age == 2
p = Person()
assert p.age == 3
print(r)
print(p)
print(vars(p))
```

Comment: I'm quite pleased with this solution. I've been experimenting all day with descriptors and dataclasses and landed on a solution very similar to yours.

This to my eyes this the best solution, as it doesn't introduce any extra fields on the class, and is easily reusable.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to get all the benefits. Note that dataclass is generating code for you, so you can do modifications by inheritance.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclasses import field
from typing import Union


class Descriptor:

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, obj_type=None):
        if obj:
            return vars(obj)[self.name]
        else:
            return None

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            value = int(value)
        vars(obj)[self.name] = value


@dataclass
class PersonData:
    name: str
    age: Union[int, str] = field(default=3, repr=False)

    # Many additional attributes you want to get the benefit of field for


class Person(PersonData):
    age = Descriptor()

    # Many additional attributes you want to use descriptors for


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Person('Mike')
    r = Person('Mary', 2)

    print(p, p.age)
    print(r, r.age)

    r.age = 5
    print(p, p.age)
    print(r, r.age)
```

You will get the following print:

```sh
Person(name='Mike') 3
Person(name='Mary') 2
Person(name='Mike') 3
Person(name='Mary') 5
```

You can see that the default value defined in `PersonData` is posted to `Person` automatically. There is no need to store `default` in `Descriptor` anymore.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of great answers, ranging from creating an intermediate dataclass and using inheritance to advanced solutions which create custom fields, but in Python 3.10, the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/dataclasses.html#descriptor-typed-fields) has finally provided an official way to do this, and it turns out the solution has always worked but just hasn't been documented yet.

Before starting however, it is worth noting that *type validation* can be done statically using tools such as `mypy` or `pyright`, which will check the types specified in your code without the need for you to check them at runtime. This means you should ideally only be doing *value validation*, such as checking `if age >= 0:`.

Additionally, implementing your own descriptors is confusing and 99% of the time unnecessary. Use `property` instead when possible.

### Hacky Typing

First, the shortest possible answer you could have. Ignore the descriptor entirely and just put in the type you want and force a casting.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import cast


@dataclass
class Person:

    def __get_age(self) -> int:
        return super().__getattr__("age")  # type: ignore

    def __set_age(self, age: int) -> None:
        if age is type(self).age:          # Default value.
            super().__setattr__("age", 0)  # Type checker ignores this case.
                                           # You may get flagged for dead code.
        elif age < 0:
            raise ValueError("expected age >= 0")
        else:
            super().__setattr__("age", age)

    # Ignore the incorrect property type with casting.
    age: int = cast(int, property(__get_age, __set_age))
```

How this works and its caveats will be explained in the following sections. Read **Applying Dataclasses** on what caveats there are to the above, especially if you need to use it in combination with a `field`.

### The Type-Hint

Now, getting onto how to implement this properly, the first step is to implement the type-hint. For this, we can use `typing.Protocol` to outline how the property should behave.

```py
import sys
from typing import Any, Optional, Protocol, TypeVar, overload

if sys.version_info < (3, 9):
    from typing import Type
else:
    from builtins import type as Type

IT = TypeVar("IT", contravariant=True)
CT = TypeVar("CT", covariant=True)
GT = TypeVar("GT", covariant=True)
ST = TypeVar("ST", contravariant=True)


class Descriptor(Protocol[CT, GT, ST]):

    # Get default attribute from a class.
    @overload
    def __get__(self, instance: None, owner: Type[Any]) -> CT:
        ...

    # Get attribute from an instance.
    @overload
    def __get__(self, instance: IT, owner: Optional[Type[IT]] = ...) -> GT:
        ...

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        ...

    def __set__(self, instance: Any, value: ST) -> None:
        ...
```

This allows us to use things like

```py
class Person:
    age: Descriptor[property, int, int]
```

to specify the class default type (`Person.age: property`), getter type (`age: int = person.age`), and setter type (`person.age: int = age`).

### Applying Dataclasses

Now comes the tricky part: how does this work with a `dataclass`? There's a few things to note:

- Use `age: Descriptor[...] = property(getter, setter)` directly if there's no need to use `field(...)`.
- Do not use `@property` as a decorator when using linters, things like `mypy` will complain.
- Use `field(default=descriptor, ...)` if you need to use a `field`.
- Do not use `field(default_factory=...)`. It turns out that the class default type *is* the default factory when it comes to descriptors.
- When using `property` and not a custom descriptor, the class default type is the `property` itself. This means you can implement the default value in your setter by checking `if value is type(self).property_name:`.
- A read-only `property` can be typed with `typing.Never` for the setter type (or `typing.NoReturn` for `sys.version_info < (3, 11)`). This is the opposite of using `typing.Any`; instead of accepting any type, it never accepts any setter type.
- This does not work with `__slots__`, since `__slots__` has to create its own descriptors in order to work. Kind of. See the section at the very end if you need to use `__slots__`.

Putting it all together for our example, here's the result:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Union


@dataclass
class Person:

    def __get_age(self) -> int:
        return super().__getattr__("age")  # type: ignore

    def __set_age(self, age: Union[int, property]) -> None:
        if age is type(self).age:
            super().__setattr__("age", 0)  # Default value.
        elif not isinstance(age, int):
            raise TypeError("age expected integer")
        elif age < 0:
            raise ValueError("expected age >= 0")
        else:
            super().__setattr__("age", age)

    age: Descriptor[property, int, Union[int, property]] = property(__get_age, __set_age)
```

### Making False Assumptions (to clean it up)

Okay, this is a little bit messy, maybe less than ideal. In particular, the setter and default value is... kind of confusing, at least when we use `property` and not our own custom `Descriptor`, which would solve the issue but again make the code more confusing. So let's make the realistic assumption that nobody is actually going to use the setter with a `property` and hide the fact that the default value is a `property` instead of an `int`. There's no point in type-checking ourselves at the cost of usability for others.

```py
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar

GT = TypeVar("GT", covariant=True)
T = TypeVar("T")


# Use `attribute: Property[GETTER, SETTER]`.
class Property(Descriptor[T, GT, T], Protocol[GT, T]):
    ...
```

Usage:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Any, cast


@dataclass
class Person:

    def __get_age(self) -> int:
        return super().__getattr__("age")  # type: ignore

    def __set_age(self, age: int) -> None:
        if age is type(self).age:          # Default value.
            super().__setattr__("age", 0)  # Type checker ignores this case.
                                           # You may get flagged for dead code.
        elif age < 0:
            raise ValueError("expected age >= 0")
        else:
            super().__setattr__("age", age)

    # Ignore the incorrect property type with casting.
    age: Property[int, int] = cast(Any, property(__get_age, __set_age))
```

With this, type-checkers will recognize that `age: int = person.age` and `person.age: int = age`, but it will mistakenly think that `age: int = Person.age` when it's actually a `property`.

### Hacky Typing

Finally, we come full circle to the first solution. If your getter and setter types are the same, you can just put in that type and instead of using a `property`, forcefully cast it into the desired type altogether. The solution is at the top, and it is by far the easiest to implement, at the potential cost of type accuracy.

### Slots

The way `__slots__` works it creates its own descriptor for each attribute, which directly write to the underlying memory in C that's optimized specifically for each attribute. The way it works with default values is that the default values are saved in the `__fields__`, which is what the `__init__` searches for. So in order to implement descriptors with slots, we would need to override the slots descriptor with our own.

The way I recommend doing this is through inheritance.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import cast


@dataclass(slots=True)
class _Person:
    age: int = 0


@dataclass(slots=True)
class Person(_Person):

    def __get_age(self) -> int:
        return super().age

    def __set_age(self, age: int) -> None:
        if age < 0:
            raise ValueError("expected age >= 0")
        else:
            super().age = age  # type: ignore

    age = cast(int, property(__get_age, __set_age))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is ok, but isn't pretty and doesn't work
My first idea was for `Descriptor` to inherit `dataclasses.Field`
but that doesn't work either

What you should do is somewhat roundabout
But, that is how things should be done even without dataclasses
It is to make 2 attributes `age` and `_age`

```py
import dataclasses as dc

class GetSet:
    def __init__(self, predicate = lambda value: True):
        self.predicate = predicate

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if isinstance(value, GetSet):
            return # init will try to assign `obj.age = GetSet(...)`, but we will ignore that
            # this actually happens because it thinks `GetSet` should be default argument
        if not self.predicate(value):
            raise ValueError
        obj._age = value

    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        if obj is not None: # called obj.age
            return obj._age
        return self # called Person.age

@dc.dataclass
class Person:
    # this one doesn't go to init, hence init=False, rest is as you wish
    _age: int = dc.field(default = 20, repr=False, init=False)
    # this one goes to init, if that is not desired, just remove annotation `: int`
    age: int = GetSet(lambda age: age >= 18) # this attribute will not be allowed to be under 18
```

and alternative is to use built-in `property`

```py
@dc.dataclass
class Person:
    _age: int = dc.field(default = 20, repr=False, init=False)
    age: int
    @property
    def age(self):
        return self._age
    @age.setter
    def age(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, property):
            return # we still need to ignore this
        if value < 18:
            raise ValueError('no underaged')
        self._age = value
```

Answer (score 0):

Using descriptor with dataclass is quite tricky and require some ugly hack to make it work (to support `default_factory`, `frozen`,...). I have some example code working in: https://github.com/google/etils/blob/main/etils/edc/field_utils.py

```py
from etils import edc  # pip install etils[edc]

@dataclasses.dataclass
class A:
  path: epath.Path = edc.field(validate=epath.Path)
  x: int = edc.field(validate=int)
  y: int = edc.field(validate=lambda x: -x, default=5)


a = A(
   path='/some/path'  # Inputs auto-normalized `str` -> `epath.Path`
   x='123',
)
assert isinstance(a.path, epath.Path)
assert a.x == 123
assert a.y == -5
```

Here is the implementation:

```py
"""Field utils."""

from __future__ import annotations

import dataclasses
import typing
from typing import Any, Callable, Generic, Optional, Type, TypeVar

_Dataclass = Any
_In = Any
_Out = Any
_InT = TypeVar('_InT')
_OutT = TypeVar('_OutT')


def field(
    *,
    validate: Optional[Callable[[_In], _OutT]] = None,
    **kwargs: Any,
) -> dataclasses.Field[_OutT]:
  """Like `dataclasses.field`, but allow `validator`.
  Args:
    validate: A callable `(x) -> x` called each time the variable is assigned.
    **kwargs: Kwargs forwarded to `dataclasses.field`
  Returns:
    The field.
  """
  if validate is None:
    return dataclasses.field(**kwargs)
  else:
    field_ = _Field(validate=validate, field_kwargs=kwargs)
    return typing.cast(dataclasses.Field, field_)


class _Field(Generic[_InT, _OutT]):
  """Field descriptor."""

  def __init__(
      self,
      validate: Callable[[_InT], _OutT],
      field_kwargs: dict[str, Any],
  ) -> None:
    """Constructor.
    Args:
      validate: A callable called each time the variable is assigned.
      field_kwargs: Kwargs forwarded to `dataclasses.field`
    """
    # Attribute name and objtype refer to the object in which the descriptor
    # is applied. E.g. if `A.x = edc.field()`:
    # * _attribute_name = 'x'
    # * _objtype = A
    self._attribute_name: Optional[str] = None
    self._objtype: Optional[Type[_Dataclass]] = None

    self._validate = validate
    self._field_kwargs = field_kwargs

    # Whether `__get__` has not been called yet. See `__get__` for details.
    self._first_getattr_call: bool = True

  def __set_name__(self, objtype: Type[_Dataclass], name: str) -> None:
    """Bind the descriptor to the class (PEP 487)."""
    self._objtype = objtype
    self._attribute_name = name

  def __get__(
      self,
      obj: Optional[_Dataclass],
      objtype: Optional[Type[_Dataclass]] = None,
  ) -> _OutT:
    """Called when `MyDataclass.x` or `my_dataclass.x`."""
    # Called as `MyDataclass.my_attribute`
    if obj is None:
      if self._first_getattr_call:
        # Count the number of times `dataclasses.dataclass(cls)` calls
        # `getattr(cls, f.name)`.
        # The first time, we return a `dataclasses.Field` to let dataclass
        # do the magic.
        # The second time, `dataclasses.dataclass` delete the descriptor if
        # `isinstance(getattr(cls, f.name, None), Field)`. So it is very
        # important to return anything except a `dataclasses.Field`.
        # This rely on implementation detail, but seems to hold for python
        # 3.6-3.10.
        self._first_getattr_call = False
        return dataclasses.field(**self._field_kwargs)
      else:
        # TODO(epot): Could better handle default value: Either by returning
        # the default value, or raising an AttributeError. Currently, we just
        # return the descriptor:
        # assert isinstance(MyDataclass.my_attribute, _Field)
        return self
    else:
      # Called as `my_dataclass.my_path`
      return _getattr(obj, self._attribute_name)

  def __set__(self, obj: _Dataclass, value: _InT) -> None:
    """Called as `my_dataclass.x = value`."""
    # Validate the value during assignement
    _setattr(obj, self._attribute_name, self._validate(value))


# Because there is one instance of the `_Field` per class, shared across all
# class instances, we need to store the per-object state somewhere.
# The simplest is to attach the state in an extra `dict[str, value]`:
# `_dataclass_field_values`.


def _getattr(
    obj: _Dataclass,
    attribute_name: str,
) -> _Out:
  """Returns the `obj.attribute_name`."""
  _init_dataclass_state(obj)
  # Accessing the attribute before it was set (e.g. before super().__init__)
  if attribute_name not in obj._dataclass_field_values:  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    raise AttributeError(
        f"type object '{type(obj).__qualname__}' has no attribute "
        f"'{attribute_name}'")
  else:
    return obj._dataclass_field_values[attribute_name]  # pylint: disable=protected-access


def _setattr(
    obj: _Dataclass,
    attribute_name: str,
    value: _In,
) -> None:
  """Set the `obj.attribute_name = value`."""
  # Note: In `dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)`, obj.__setattr__ will
  # correctly raise a `FrozenInstanceError` before `DataclassField.__set__` is
  # called.
  _init_dataclass_state(obj)
  obj._dataclass_field_values[attribute_name] = value  # pylint: disable=protected-access


def _init_dataclass_state(obj: _Dataclass) -> None:
  """Initialize the object state containing all DataclassField values."""
  if not hasattr(obj, '_dataclass_field_values'):
    # Use object.__setattr__ for frozen dataclasses
    object.__setattr__(obj, '_dataclass_field_values', {})
```

There might be simpler way, but this one was fully tested.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to your question directly, but you can easily modify this by either adding a validator or by using `on_set` directly.

This is how I extend dataclass field so that it works as a descriptor (property) directly:

```py
from dataclasses import _MISSING_TYPE, MISSING, Field, dataclass, field

class MyField(Field):
    def __init__(self, on_set: Callable[[T], T]|None=None, default: Any = MISSING, default_factory: Callable|_MISSING_TYPE = MISSING, init: bool = True, repr: bool = True, hash: bool|None = None, compare: bool = True, metadata : Mapping|None = None, kw_only : bool|_MISSING_TYPE = MISSING):
        """Dataclass field (Field) extension. Refer to dataclass docs for respective fields.

        * `on_set`: Callable - extra function to be used on Python property update. Could be used for cleanup, for example (str strip). Value is given as is, including None. So the function given should be aware of that. No extra logic is applied. Default = None.
        """
        super().__init__(default=default, default_factory=default_factory, init=init, repr=repr, hash=hash, compare=compare, metadata=metadata, kw_only=kw_only)
        self.on_set = on_set
        self.__first_get_request = True

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        """ __set_name__ initializer for properties as per [PEP-487](https://peps.python.org/pep-0487/)"""
        self.name = name
        self.__name = "__"+self.name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        # There are 2 get requests coming on dataclass creation with no instance set. On the first request we need to supply the descriptor itself (self), on all other requests - actual values (default for no instance case).
        if instance is None and self.__first_get_request:
            self.__first_get_request = False
            return self
        value = instance.__dict__.get(self.__name, MISSING) if instance else MISSING
        if value is not MISSING:
            return value
        if self.default is not MISSING:
            return self.default
        if self.default_factory is not MISSING:
            return self.default_factory()
        raise ValueError(f"Wasn't able to retrieve value for field '{self.name}'. No defaults and not initialized?")

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        """ Descriptor's setter - if on_set was given during init - call on_set and use its returned value. Otherwise just update value as is."""
        if self.on_set:
            instance.__dict__[self.__name] = self.on_set(value)
        else:
            instance.__dict__[self.__name] = value
```

And actual code for a class might be something like:

```py
@dataclass
class A:
    a: str = MyField(on_set=lambda value: value and value.strip(), default="")
```