# How to get the index of a dataclass field

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, python-dataclasses

Say I have a simple dataclass instance

```python
import dataclasses as dc

@dc.dataclass
class DCItem:
    name: str
    unit_price: float

item = DCItem('test', 11)
```

Now I want to determine the position (index) of instance attribute ***item.unit_price***. How can I make it simple to use and performant? I thought about using a get method using *dc.asdict*

```python
@dc.dataclass
class DCItem:
    name: str
    unit_price: float

    def get_index(self, name):
        return list(dc.asdict(self)).index(name)

item.get_index('unit_price')  # 1
```

But this has two drawbacks:

1. It's not very performant, at least not for many instance attributes
2. It looses the nice auto-completion feature of *item.unit_price*

Is there a solution that combines the features of a dataclass with that of IntEnum and enum.auto() without the above drawbacks?

Comment: No there isn't. Why are you turning attribute names into integers in the first place? That's a very unusual thing to do. There may be a better way to implement this.

Comment: **Why** do you need to know the _index_ of a field?

Comment: Each field in my dataclass corresponds to a column in a table. The dataclass corresponds to the underlying datamodel. I want to use it to easily access each column and fill it with values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class is not going to be changed at runtime, you can cache indexes in a class attribute as a dictionary.

```
import dataclasses as dc

@dc.dataclass
class DCItem:
    name: str
    unit_price: float
    
    @classmethod
    def get_index(cls, name):
        if '_idx_mapping' not in cls.__dict__:
            flds = dc.fields(cls)
            cls._idx_mapping = {flds[idx].name: idx for idx in range(len(flds))}
        return cls._idx_mapping[name]


>>> item = DCItem('test', 11)
>>> item.get_index('unit_price')
1
```

Accessing dictionary should be fast - *O(n)* in the worst case.

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit("item.get_index('unit_price')", "from __main__ import item")
0.21372696105390787
```

For comparison, your solution is quite slow, as you mentioned:

```
>>> timeit("item.get_index('unit_price')", "from __main__ import item")
4.260601775022224
```

**Note**: I haven't tested this class with inheritance.

---

**EDIT**: Solving the second point makes the solution more complex. I've come up with the following using Python descriptors.

```py
import dataclasses as dc
from typing import Any
from collections import defaultdict


class IndexedField:
    def __init__(self, a_type: type, value: Any, index: int):
        self._validate_type(a_type, value)  # This line can be removed when type checking is not required.
        self._a_type = a_type
        self._value = value
        self._index = index

    @staticmethod
    def _validate_type(a_type: type, value: Any):
        if not isinstance(value, a_type):
            raise TypeError(f"value is of type {type(value)} but {a_type} is expected")

    @property
    def a_type(self):  # read-only
        return self._a_type

    @property
    def index(self):  # read-only
        return self._index

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, new_value):
        self._validate_type(self._a_type, new_value)  # This line can be removed when type checking is not required.
        self._value = new_value

    def __repr__(self):
        return (f'{self.__class__.__name__}'
                f'(a_type={self._a_type!r}, index={self._index!r}, value={self._value!r})')


class IndexedFieldDescriptor:
    _class_last_index = defaultdict(int)
    _class_indexes = defaultdict(dict)

    def __init__(self, a_type) -> None:
        self._name = None
        self._type = a_type

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return instance.__dict__[self._name]

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self._name = name
        self._class_indexes[owner.__name__][name] = self._class_last_index[owner.__name__]
        self._class_last_index[owner.__name__] += 1

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        index = self._class_indexes[instance.__class__.__name__][self._name]
        instance.__dict__[self._name] = IndexedField(self._type, value, index)


@dc.dataclass
class DCItem:
    name: IndexedField = IndexedFieldDescriptor(str)
    unit_price: IndexedField = IndexedFieldDescriptor(float)


item = DCItem('test', 11.0)
print(item)
print(f"* name field value: {item.name.value!r}, name field index: {item.name.index!r}, name field type: {item.name.a_type!r}")
print(f"* unit_price field value: {item.unit_price.value!r}, unit_price field index: {item.unit_price.index!r}, unit_price field type: {item.unit_price.a_type!r}")

from timeit import timeit
print(f'* Index access time: {timeit("item.name.index", "from __main__ import item")}')
print(f'* Value access time: {timeit("item.name.value", "from __main__ import item")}')
```

***Output:***

```
DCItem(name=IndexedField(a_type=<class 'str'>, index=0, value='test'), unit_price=IndexedField(a_type=<class 'float'>, index=1, value=11.0))
* name field value: 'test', name field index: 0, name field type: <class 'str'>
* unit_price field value: 11.0, unit_price field index: 1, unit_price field type: <class 'float'>
* Index access time: 0.2253845389932394
* Value access time: 0.2729280750500038
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves the performance issue. However, it doesn't solve point 2: The index cannot be accessed easily by dot accessing item.unit_price.index or similar.
Can it be done by using a descriptor like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69427203/18281361?

Comment: If you want to use the dot notation to access `index`, `name` and `unit_price` can't be one of the built-in types. I've created a new class `IndexedField` that stores a value, an index and a type. After instantiation, you can access those attributes as `item.unit_price.value`, `item.unit_price.index`, etc. Auto-completion should work as well. See the edited answer.

Comment: This is great. Now we have a Python dataclass that can be used as data model for GUI tables. The crucial descriptor method is [__set_name__](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#customized-names), which keeps track of the index.